# Yosemite Keychain Access Not Showing Keychain List

Tags: macos, keychain, sidebar

I have Yosemite, and my Keychain Access only shows the login keychain, giving me no option to switch between keychains.

[image]

As you can see, my sidebar on the left is missing. I try toggling it with ⌘+K, but to no avail.

[image]

Pressing that button repeatedly, thereby supposedly hiding and showing the keychain sidebar, doesn't do anything.

What might be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you solve this problem i have the same problem but can't figure out how to solve it. I've already deleted my com.apple.keychainaccess.plist file in /Library/Preferences but this doesn't seem to help

Comment: No, sorry, I never solved it.